# Is there a way to get the iteration number with angular foreach on an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any way I can get the iteration number inside an angular foreach (when iterating through an object like : `{'foo': 'blah', 'blah': 'foo'}` ? 
So with my iterator function in that case, value will be 'blah' and then 'foo' while key will be 'foo' and then 'blah'

Comment: Did you try reading the docs? it is explained there. Please read the manual before asking questions that are already documented and very easy to find

Comment: Read the documentation about foreach here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Comment: key act as index  in angular.forEach

Comment: Thanks lads, read the question better please ...

Comment: Ohhh you want the iteration number not index, just to clarify `$index` in an `ngRepeat` is not its iteration number, but the current index in the array. There is an important difference when you start splicing up arrays. I think that comparison is what is confusing people, myself included at first. In a nut shell no unless you have a global variable you manually increment.

Comment: Ok thanks, indeed, my very bad :s

Answer (score 0):

Angulars `forEach` when iterating an object doesn't tell you how many times its iterated that objects keys.

When iterating an array it doesn't tell you how many times its ran but its current position in the array. It's probably just me being pedantic but there is a difference.

However an alternative that could give its current position in the objects keys would be to use the native `Object.keys()`. It will return an array of the objects keys, you can then iterate over them like a normal array and get your current position in that array.

```
var obj = {'foo': 'blah', 'blah': 'foo'};

Object.keys(obj)
    .forEach(function (key, index) {
        console.log('Key', key, 'Value', obj[key]);
        console.log('Ive ran ', index);
    });
```

DOCS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score -1):

Yes, like this:

```
angular.forEach(array, function (item, index) {
    //index
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is the second parameter that gets passed in to the foreach function call directly from the angular documentation

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

```
angular.forEach(obj, iterator, [context]);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
angular.forEach(var,function(value,key){
  console.log(key);
})
```